# How to implement tab containers in web-application?

Tags: ajax, user-interface, web-applications, dojo, struts

In modern web browsers we can work with multiple contents in parallel by using tab containers. It took me quite some time to mimic a similar behavior within a webpage of a web-app by using a library called Struts Menu. The solution as far as I understand is basically a combination of using CSS with calling JSP pages.

I was wondering if there are other/easier options to render html content depending on the state of a tab select box in top of the page?

- Do you have ideas and/or examples for implementing a tab container with JSP?
- Do you have ideas and/or examples for implementing a tab container with Dojo/Ajax?
- Do you have ideas and/or examples for implementing a tab container with Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dojo's dijit TabContainer. Some examples and documentation [here](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/layout/TabContainer-examples)